# Why error appear when I apply function to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, typeerror

```
def function(s):
    if (s['col1'] == 'something1')|(s['col1'] == 'smth2')|(s['col1'] == 'smth3'):
        return 'A'
    elif (s['col1'] == 'smth4')|(s['col1'] == 'smth5'):
        return 'B'
    elif (s['col1'] == 'smth6')|(s['col1'] == 'smth7'):
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'D'
```

The function above worked. But when I apply it to dataframe:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(function, axis = 1)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: ("'bool' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not another variable called `function` that overwrote the actual function definition?

Comment: For me working correct.

Comment: No, there is no a variable called function.

Answer (score 1):

For me working correct, here ia alternative solution with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['something1','jeff bridges','smth7','billy boy','smth5']})


print (df)

def function(s):
    if (s['col1'] == 'something1')|(s['col1'] == 'smth2')|(s['col1'] == 'smth3'):
        return 'A'
    elif (s['col1'] == 'smth4')|(s['col1'] == 'smth5'):
        return 'B'
    elif (s['col1'] == 'smth6')|(s['col1'] == 'smth7'):
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'D'
    
df['new_col'] = df.apply(function, axis = 1)
```

---

```
m1 = df['col1'].isin(['something1','smth2','smth3'])
m2 = df['col1'].isin(['smth4','smth5'])
m3 = df['col1'].isin(['smth6','smth7'])

df['new_col1'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['A','B','C'], default='D')
print (df)
           col1 new_col new_col1
0    something1       A        A
1  jeff bridges       D        D
2         smth7       C        C
3     billy boy       D        D
4         smth5       B        B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, second one worked but I didn't understand why anther one doesn't work?

Comment: @SaidTaxmezov - Hard quesdtion, for me working correct. If change function name not help?